# R programming tutorial > How do I subset for either columns when I calculate the mean?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am learning R atm, one of the exercise is to create a program to read mean for column "sulfate" or column "nitrate".  However, I am only be able to get correct mean for one of the columns not all.
Can you please give me some help on How do I subset for either columns when I calculate the mean?

Following steps I have taken to copmlete the exercise
1. create a list of files # combine all files into one data frame.
2. create an empty data frame
3. loops through the files then rbinding them together
4. subset a data frame
5. calculate mean for column(s)

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:132){
  files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)   #creates a list of files
  dat <- data.frame()                                   #creates an empty data frame
  for (i in 1:132) {                                
    #loops through the files, rbinding them together 
    dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
  }
  dat_subset <- dat[which(dat$ID %in% id),names(dat) %in% c("sulfate","nitrate")]
  mean(dat_subset[, "sulfate"], na.rm=TRUE)      #identifies the mean  while stripping out the NAs for "sulfate"
  mean(dat_subset[, "nitrate"], na.rm=TRUE)      #identifies the mean  while stripping out the NAs for "nitrate"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10) ## [1] 4.064128 
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72) ## [1] 1.706047 
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23) ## [1] 1.280833
```

**Actual output:**

[image]

I have also tried to fix it by combining the two columns into one, it will return NaN instead...

```
mean(dat_subset[,c("sulfate","nitrate")], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: When you do `pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)` you would expect mean of only "sulfate" column for id 1 to 10 right? That doesn't seem to be included in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to subset the "rows" based on the input "id", you could do the following after you create your dataframe as Linog suggested

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory=NULL,pollutant,id=1:132){
  #create a list of files

  dat_subset <- dat[id,]
  print(mean(dat_subset[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)  )    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a very concise solution based on `data.table`. You can make your operation over several columns at the same time

```r
library(data.table)

pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:132){
   files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)   #creates a list of files
   dat <- lapply(files_list, fread)
   dat <- rbindlist(dat, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

   output <- dat[get('ID') %in% id),lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=TRUE)]
   return(output)
}

pollutantmean(directory, c("nitrate","sulfate"), 1:10)
pollutantmean(directory, "nitrate", 1:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can read files mentioned in `id` and combine them, subset the columns mentioned in `pollutant` and take the mean. Using base R, we can do :

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory,pollutant,id=1:132){

   files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)   
   dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_list[id], read.csv))
   #For one column
   mean(dat[[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE)
   #For multiple columns
   #colMeans(dat[pollutant], na.rm = TRUE)

}

pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```